# Google Maps DirectionsRenderer change draggable

Tags: maps, renderer, directions

I want to let the user change, if the route can be changed by dragging.

The option is enabled in the DirectionsRenderer

```
var rendererOptions = {
draggable: true
};
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
```

With a checkbox I let the user change the draggability.

```
function allowMove() {
if (directionsDisplay.draggable) {
    directionsDisplay.draggable = false;
} 
else {
    directionsDisplay.draggable = true;
}
;
}
```

But it only changes after an action (dragging) (and that only disables it after an action)

I found an event **draggable_changed** but I dont know what to do in these event..

And if it would be possible to click on the route it would be great, because I am displaying the height of the clicked position, but it wont work on the route ( also with disabled dragging, but nearer than with )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried
`directionsDisplay.setOptions({draggable: !directionsDisplay.draggable});`?